# Adding elements generated by innerHtml to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml, createelement

I was wondering if there is a way to add elements generated by innerHtml. It's not that hard to do with createElement but for me innerHtml feels just more logical and easy. I made a example code to show my problem:

Create element:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
let squares = []


function createGrid() {
    
    for (let i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    square.classList.add('square')
    grid.appendChild(square) 
    squares.push(square)
    }
}

function hideSquare(){
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
squares[random].style.display = "none"
}
```

innerHtml:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
let squares = []


function createGrid() {
    
    for (let i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    grid.innerHtml += `<div class="square"></div>`
    // ???
    }
}

function hideSquare(){
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
squares[random].style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: The `grid.innerHtml +=` is slow and a repeated assignment should be avoided whenever possible. A better approach would be to generate the HTML-string containing all grid elements and then assign it _once_ to `grid.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lastChild` to get the div you just inserted (note I added the `id` in the code below just to visualize the order), also, it is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
let squares = [];

function createGrid() {
    for (let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      grid.innerHTML += `<div id="square-${i+1}" class="square"></div>`;
      squares.push(grid.lastChild);
    }
}

createGrid();

console.log(squares);
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. Also i was writing code here so i just forgot about these uppercases

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach wirh `.innerHTML`:

```js
function createGrid(n) {
  // assign the innerHTML only ONCE:
  grid.innerHTML = [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => `<div class="square">${i}</div>`).join("\n");
  return [...grid.querySelectorAll(".square")]  // return all DOM elements in an array
}

function shfl(a) { // Durstenfeld shuffle
  for (let j, i = a.length; i > 1;) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i--);
    if (i != j)[a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]]
  }
  return a
}

const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const squares = shfl(createGrid(30));
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => squares.length && (squares.pop().style.visibility = "hidden");
```

```css
.square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<button>hide a square</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

The original `hideSquare()` function had the problem, that a hidden square could have been chosen again for hiding, giving the user the impression that the click "didn't work". By shuffling the array of all squares once and then hiding the elements one after the other this problem is avoided.

Comment: Message to @Anna_b : If you are still interested in a solution to your [random shapes question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70950893/how-to-code-a-random-shape-generator-with-p5-js) - I have a solution ready! You can undeleted your post, then I can add the answer there.